# Half-life Probability

Tags: probability

When trying to answer a probability question a while back, I came upon a fundamental issue embodied by the following problem.

Suppose there is a block of 200 atoms, each with a half-life of 60 years. What is the probability that 10 or more atoms decay in a given 1-year period?

Comment: So, for a given atom, the probability that it decays within an arbitrary interval of $60$ years is $1/2$ (given that it had not decayed at the beginning of those $60$ years). What do you think is the probability that it decays within a single given year?

Comment: Can you really do it with proportions?

Comment: Isn't the probability for one atom something like .5^t

Comment: Yes, the probability of a single atom not having decayed after a time $t$ is $0.5^t$, if your unit of time is $60$ years. Now you just have to express $1$ year in that scale, and you're halfway to an answer.

Comment: So how does that justify using proportions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $P(t)$ equal the number of atoms left after $t$ years.

Then $P(t)=200*\left(\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\displaystyle\frac{t}{60}}$

Note that $P(1)\approx197.028041$

Let $x$ equal the probability that an atom decays after 1 year. Then $x=\displaystyle \frac{200-197.028041}{200} \approx 1.1485979\%$.
Note that this is equivalent to $1-\displaystyle\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\displaystyle\frac{1}{60}}$

The probability that 10 or more atoms will decay is equal to $\displaystyle\sum_{n=10}^{200}\left(\binom{200}{n}*x^n*(1-x)^{(200-n)}\right)=1-\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{9}\left(\binom{200}{n}*x^n*(1-x)^{(200-n)}\right)\approx0.0124372\%$

(P.S. My math might be a little off, I am only a high school freshman)